# Failed to load audio from <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7b01dd5f8b80>

Tags: audio, google-colaboratory, kaggle, huggingface-datasets

I'm encountering an audio processing issue specifically on Kaggle, while the same code works without errors on Colab

```
voices = datasets.map(prepare_dataset, remove_columns=datasets.column_names["train"])
```

prepare_dataset function

```
import librosa

def prepare_dataset(batch):
    audio = batch["audio"]
    resampled_audio = librosa.resample(audio["array"], orig_sr=audio["sampling_rate"], target_sr=16000)

    batch["input_features"] = feature_extractor(resampled_audio, sampling_rate=16000).input_features[0]
    batch["labels"] = tokenizer(batch["sentence"]).input_ids
    return batch
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 1
----> 1 voices = datasets.map(prepare_dataset, remove_columns=datasets.column_names["train"])

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/dataset_dict.py:438, in DatasetDict.map(self, function, with_indices, with_rank, input_columns, batched, batch_size, drop_last_batch, remove_columns, keep_in_memory, load_from_cache_file, cache_file_names, writer_batch_size, features, disable_nullable, fn_kwargs, num_proc, desc)
    435 if cache_file_names is None:
    436     cache_file_names = {k: None for k in self}
    437 return DatasetDict(
--> 438     {
    439         k: dataset.map(
    440             function=function,
    441             with_indices=with_indices,
    442             with_rank=with_rank,
    443             input_columns=input_columns,
    444             batched=batched,
    445             batch_size=batch_size,
    446             drop_last_batch=drop_last_batch,
    447             remove_columns=remove_columns,
    448             keep_in_memory=keep_in_memory,
    449             load_from_cache_file=load_from_cache_file,
    450             cache_file_name=cache_file_names[k],
    451             writer_batch_size=writer_batch_size,
    452             features=features,
    453             disable_nullable=disable_nullable,
    454             fn_kwargs=fn_kwargs,
    455             num_proc=num_proc,
    456             desc=desc,
    457         )
    458         for k, dataset in self.items()
    459     }
    460 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/dataset_dict.py:439, in <dictcomp>(.0)
    435 if cache_file_names is None:
    436     cache_file_names = {k: None for k in self}
    437 return DatasetDict(
    438     {
--> 439         k: dataset.map(
    440             function=function,
    441             with_indices=with_indices,
    442             with_rank=with_rank,
    443             input_columns=input_columns,
    444             batched=batched,
    445             batch_size=batch_size,
    446             drop_last_batch=drop_last_batch,
    447             remove_columns=remove_columns,
    448             keep_in_memory=keep_in_memory,
    449             load_from_cache_file=load_from_cache_file,
    450             cache_file_name=cache_file_names[k],
    451             writer_batch_size=writer_batch_size,
    452             features=features,
    453             disable_nullable=disable_nullable,
    454             fn_kwargs=fn_kwargs,
    455             num_proc=num_proc,
    456             desc=desc,
    457         )
    458         for k, dataset in self.items()
    459     }
    460 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py:1955, in Dataset.map(self, function, with_indices, with_rank, input_columns, batched, batch_size, drop_last_batch, remove_columns, keep_in_memory, load_from_cache_file, cache_file_name, writer_batch_size, features, disable_nullable, fn_kwargs, num_proc, suffix_template, new_fingerprint, desc)
   1952 disable_tqdm = not logging.is_progress_bar_enabled()
   1954 if num_proc is None or num_proc == 1:
-> 1955     return self._map_single(
   1956         function=function,
   1957         with_indices=with_indices,
   1958         with_rank=with_rank,
   1959         input_columns=input_columns,
   1960         batched=batched,
   1961         batch_size=batch_size,
   1962         drop_last_batch=drop_last_batch,
   1963         remove_columns=remove_columns,
   1964         keep_in_memory=keep_in_memory,
   1965         load_from_cache_file=load_from_cache_file,
   1966         cache_file_name=cache_file_name,
   1967         writer_batch_size=writer_batch_size,
   1968         features=features,
   1969         disable_nullable=disable_nullable,
   1970         fn_kwargs=fn_kwargs,
   1971         new_fingerprint=new_fingerprint,
   1972         disable_tqdm=disable_tqdm,
   1973         desc=desc,
   1974     )
   1975 else:
   1977     def format_cache_file_name(cache_file_name, rank):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py:520, in transmit_tasks.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    518     self: "Dataset" = kwargs.pop("self")
    519 # apply actual function
--> 520 out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    521 datasets: List["Dataset"] = list(out.values()) if isinstance(out, dict) else [out]
    522 for dataset in datasets:
    523     # Remove task templates if a column mapping of the template is no longer valid

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py:487, in transmit_format.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    480 self_format = {
    481     "type": self._format_type,
    482     "format_kwargs": self._format_kwargs,
    483     "columns": self._format_columns,
    484     "output_all_columns": self._output_all_columns,
    485 }
    486 # apply actual function
--> 487 out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    488 datasets: List["Dataset"] = list(out.values()) if isinstance(out, dict) else [out]
    489 # re-apply format to the output

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/fingerprint.py:458, in fingerprint_transform.<locals>._fingerprint.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    452             kwargs[fingerprint_name] = update_fingerprint(
    453                 self._fingerprint, transform, kwargs_for_fingerprint
    454             )
    456 # Call actual function
--> 458 out = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    460 # Update fingerprint of in-place transforms + update in-place history of transforms
    462 if inplace:  # update after calling func so that the fingerprint doesn't change if the function fails

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py:2320, in Dataset._map_single(self, function, with_indices, with_rank, input_columns, batched, batch_size, drop_last_batch, remove_columns, keep_in_memory, load_from_cache_file, cache_file_name, writer_batch_size, features, disable_nullable, fn_kwargs, new_fingerprint, rank, offset, disable_tqdm, desc, cache_only)
   2318 if not batched:
   2319     for i, example in enumerate(pbar):
-> 2320         example = apply_function_on_filtered_inputs(example, i, offset=offset)
   2321         if update_data:
   2322             if i == 0:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py:2220, in Dataset._map_single.<locals>.apply_function_on_filtered_inputs(inputs, indices, check_same_num_examples, offset)
   2218 if with_rank:
   2219     additional_args += (rank,)
-> 2220 processed_inputs = function(*fn_args, *additional_args, **fn_kwargs)
   2221 if update_data is None:
   2222     # Check if the function returns updated examples
   2223     update_data = isinstance(processed_inputs, (Mapping, pa.Table))

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py:1915, in Dataset.map.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.decorated(item, *args, **kwargs)
   1911 decorated_item = (
   1912     Example(item, features=self.features) if not batched else Batch(item, features=self.features)
   1913 )
   1914 # Use the LazyDict internally, while mapping the function
-> 1915 result = f(decorated_item, *args, **kwargs)
   1916 # Return a standard dict
   1917 return result.data if isinstance(result, LazyDict) else result

Cell In[17], line 7, in prepare_dataset(batch)
      6 def prepare_dataset(batch):
----> 7     audio = batch["audio"]
      8     orig_sr = audio["sampling_rate"]
     10     # Resample audio to the target sampling rate (e.g., 16000)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py:117, in Example.__getitem__(self, key)
    115 value = super().__getitem__(key)
    116 if self.features and key in self.features:
--> 117     value = decode_nested_example(self.features[key], value) if value is not None else None
    118     self[key] = value
    119     del self.features[key]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/features/features.py:1087, in decode_nested_example(schema, obj)
   1085 # Object with special decoding:
   1086 elif isinstance(schema, (Audio, Image)):
-> 1087     return schema.decode_example(obj) if obj is not None else None
   1088 return obj

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/features/audio.py:103, in Audio.decode_example(self, value)
    101     raise ValueError(f"An audio sample should have one of 'path' or 'bytes' but both are None in {value}.")
    102 elif path is not None and path.endswith("mp3"):
--> 103     array, sampling_rate = self._decode_mp3(file if file else path)
    104 elif path is not None and path.endswith("opus"):
    105     if file:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/features/audio.py:241, in Audio._decode_mp3(self, path_or_file)
    238 except RuntimeError as err:
    239     raise ImportError("To support decoding 'mp3' audio files, please install 'sox'.") from err
--> 241 array, sampling_rate = torchaudio.load(path_or_file, format="mp3")
    242 if self.sampling_rate and self.sampling_rate != sampling_rate:
    243     if not hasattr(self, "_resampler") or self._resampler.orig_freq != sampling_rate:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchaudio/backend/sox_io_backend.py:226, in load(filepath, frame_offset, num_frames, normalize, channels_first, format)
    224 buffer_size = get_buffer_size()
    225 if format == "mp3":
--> 226     return _fallback_load_fileobj(
    227         filepath,
    228         frame_offset,
    229         num_frames,
    230         normalize,
    231         channels_first,
    232         format,
    233         buffer_size,
    234     )
    235 warnings.warn(_deprecation_message)
    236 ret = torchaudio.lib._torchaudio_sox.load_audio_fileobj(
    237     filepath, frame_offset, num_frames, normalize, channels_first, format
    238 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchaudio/backend/sox_io_backend.py:34, in _fail_load_fileobj(fileobj, *args, **kwargs)
     33 def _fail_load_fileobj(fileobj, *args, **kwargs):
---> 34     raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to load audio from {fileobj}")

RuntimeError: Failed to load audio from <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7b01dd5f8b80>
```